# Write inline javascript if statement onclick or any other JS event?

Tags: javascript, inline, keyboard-events

I need to write one liner code with a if condition in JS like below:

```
onkeyup="javascript:if(event.keyCode ==13){myfunction(document.getElementById('xyz').value);}"
```

But above code dose not works for me. If i go for some creating a function and calling it from `onKeyUp` event with the same code that works like a charm.

It would be great if some one can help in this case.

Comment: Should work, but remove the `javascript:` anyway - in the context of an event handler, it's just a label and serves no real purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

I have added

```
    function myfunction(x)
    {
          alert(x);
    }
```

and have not changed the onkeyup function.
It may so be happening that you function myfunction may be declared below the body. Just wrap that code within **<head> section of the page**. 
If you are calling on document.ready then it that function isnt fidding the DOM is parsed.

Check the jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/E5DK7/

Comment: why cant we add function in line?

Comment: Adding a function inline would be function declaration. Events only invoke functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here, take your pick - an inline handler just as you've used, or one attached with `addEventListener` - they both function in Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m.

Note that your example uses a hard-coded ID in the inline javascript, while the other one I present does not. I've only given the second `input` element an id so that I can target it in `onDocLoaded` - that is to say, `myFunction2` can be attached to any element, to be fired on either keyboard event - `keyup` or `keydown`

Since `myFunction2` becomes a part of whichever element it's attached to, the `this` keyword refers to the triggering element itself. Soooo, you could create input elements without IDs with javascript, and `myFunction2` would still provide meaningful results. (The `this` keyword refers to the triggering element, so there's no need to target any single element in the event handler's body - the 1 single function can be attached without modification to any input element's `keyup`/`keydown` event that you like)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('abc').addEventListener('keyup', myFunction2, false);
}

function myFunction(input)
{
    alert(input);
}

function myFunction2(evt)
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 13)
        myFunction( this.value );
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='xyz' onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) { myFunction(byId('xyz').value); }"/>
    <hr>
    <input id='abc' />
</body>
</html>
```